# Haskell: Scope of variable when using lambda expression with bind functions

Tags: haskell, lambda, scope, bind, monads

The following line works as expected, but I am a little concerned why:

```
getLine >>= \x-> getLine >>= \y-> return [x, y]
```

Consider the addition of parenthesis to scope the lambda expressions:

```
getLine >>= (\x-> getLine) >>= (\y-> return [x, y])
```

The second line is errorneous because `x` is not in scope when used in the `return`, and I am happy with this. What concerns me this that in the first line the scope of `x` appears to have 'leaked' out.

Is this 'leaking' considered bad practice? I am confused as to how it has remained in scope and not been lost immediately after the `\x -> getLine` expression.

Comment: @sepp2k has the correct answer. Also note that if you actually try to write your second line, with parentheses, you'll get an "not in scope" error.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You parentheses are simply set wrong. The correct parentheses are

```
getLine >>= (\x -> getLine >>= (\y -> return [x, y]))
```

And therefore, `x` is of course defined in the body.

Note that this feature is particularly useful since you can format code like this:

```
getLine >>= \x ->
getLine >>= \y ->
return [x, y]
```

which is almost

```
do
  x <- getLine
  y <- getLine
  return [x, y]
```

but without any special syntax.

Answer (score 13):

If you parenthesize your first line correctly according to haskell's precedence rules, you get:

```
getLine >>= (\x-> getLine >>= (\y-> return [x, y]))
```

This makes it obvious that the second lambda is inside the first, so there's no problem with it accessing the variables of the first lambda.

Answer (score 2):

Haskell syntax follows the "maximal munch" rule: each syntax elements extends as far as it possibly can until extending it any further would result in an error. Since it works fine to extend the scope of the "`\x ->`" all the way to the end, that's what it does.

Answer (score 1):

The reference to `x` in the `return` expression is known as a [closure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(computer_science)). It's a typical feature of functional programming languages. In a pure functional programming language, like Haskell, there is no cause for concern. It's a very nice feature. In 'hybrid' functional programming languages like F# (and C# these days), closures can indeed result in unexpected behavior sometimes.

Comment: Sorry, this hasn't been asked.

Comment: Rather I would say: it doesn't seem to address the question. Dave didn't seem to be asking about closures in general, and definitely not about closures in languages other than Haskell; he seemed to be asking how this was a properly constructed closure, since it didn't look to him like `x` was within the scope of the closure.

Comment: @Owen S "Is this 'leaking' considered bad practice?"  He did ask if it is good practice.  And filling in the answer with a mention of similarities and differences in other languages does seam appropriate.